# How to detect if inside a Community in a self-registration page?

Tags: community, customer-portal, customer-community

Inspecting the self registration code added when Communities are turned on in a dev org, it appears that when a user self-registers a different API call should be used to setup the `User` (compared to older portal code). I have an existing self-registration page that I would like to work in both setups. Is there a reliable way to programmatically detect in Apex that the page is running inside a Community and so make the correct call? That is, what code could replace the `???` here:

```
Boolean isCommunity = ???;
Id userId = isCommunity
        ? Site.createExternalUser(u, c.accountId, null, true)
        : Site.createPortalUser(u, c.AccountId, null, true);
```

Comment: did you check the Site class? It has methods which run in community context Site.BaseURL() OR Site.getType()?

Comment: @RedDevil Yep `Site.getType()` returns "ChatterNetwork" which is consistent with the [site documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm?search_text=Site%20class). If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check site class it has method gettype which can give you the context from which you are running the code.

```
Site.getType();
```